# Getting basic profile and email address through linked api

Tags: php, linkedin-api

I have integerated linkedin in my website in php. When user click on a button 'connect with linkedin.' The user is redirected to the linkedin login page. When user logs in, it is redirected to the page I have defined. The problem is how can I retrieve user's basic profile and email address after the user has logged in. I referred to this link for asisstance 
http://developer.linkedin.com/documents/authentication

Here is my code for redirecting to the linkedin authorization page:

header('Location: ' . 'https://www.linkedin.com/uas/oauth2/authorization?response_type=code&&client_id=1ba8ogpm9e05&scope=r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress&state=STATE&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1/linkedin/test.php');

in this url the redirect_uri is the page where to redirect the user after authorization. So how do I retrieve user basic profile and email address?

Answer (score 1):

I implemented linkedin api in ZF2.

Please set the callback url like access and secret key of linkedIn api.

```
$content = $linkedInObject->getProfile("~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url)");
$profile = $this->objectToArray($content); 


/*

public $base_url = "http://api.linkedin.com";
public $secure_base_url = "https://api.linkedin.com";
public $oauth_callback = "oob";

*/
function getProfile($resource = "~")
    {
            $profile_url = $this->base_url . "/v1/people/" . $resource;
            $request = OAuthRequest::from_consumer_and_token($this->consumer, $this->access_token, "GET", $profile_url);
            $request->sign_request($this->signature_method, $this->consumer, $this->access_token);
            $auth_header = $request->to_header("https://api.linkedin.com"); # this is the realm

            $response = $this->httpRequest($profile_url, $auth_header, "GET");
            return $response;
    }
```

// Modified for ZF2 but in your case
 http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,picture-url)

Now you can get First name  as $profile['first-name'].

Thanks

Comment: There is no function named getProfile in my linkedin_3.2.0.class.php class file